# create hyperlink from database MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I want to get the registered users list on a page but not just their names, but with clickable hyperlink that will lead to their profiles. I have fetched their names but just in text form but how to add hyperlink to that text so that link should lead to their profile.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dva");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM apnt");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<li>";echo "User Reg.";
  echo $row['name'];
  echo " at ";
  echo $row['time'];
  echo " on ";
  echo $row['day'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  ;
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have got the data from the database and successfully printed it on the page via above code but the hyperlink still needs to be generated and I need help in that please.

Comment: are you search about that?

Comment: `echo '<a href="profile.php?id=' . $row["id"]; . '">Go to profile</a>'`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a profile.php and use GET to get the id number of your user which you send through with the link you create where you fetch your users.